# Como gerar uma lista definida pelo usuário?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

Quero criar uma lista onde o usuário define a quantidade de itens da lista e pede ao usuário cada item dela.

Fiz dessa forma:

```
n = int(input("Digite a quantidade de células da sua lista: "))

cont = 1

lista = []

for i in range(n):

  lista += (input("Informe o valor de x%d: " % (i+1)))

vetor_original = lista

print(f"Vetor Original {vetor_original}")
```

No print aparece **Nossa lista é [aparece os elementos dentro de 'x']**

E queria que aparecesse sem ''

Comment: Pesquise sobre o `append` da lista no Python.

Comment: eu consegui fazer de uma maneira, porém ainda tenho um pequeno problema

Comment: E você irá descrever isso na pergunta?

Comment: atualizei a questão mostrando como ela está agora

Comment: `lista += input(...)`, você está criando uma lista de strings, por isso aparece as aspas.

Comment: verdade, obrigadaaa

Comment: quando coloco o int na frente aparece uma mensagem de erro, eu deveria usar int?

Comment: aparece a seguinte mensagem TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: outro problema que notei é que quando coloco um número de duas casas eles aparecem como dois elementos da lista e não como um só

Answer (score 3):

```
lista = []

for i in range(n):
  lista += input("Informe o valor de x%d: " % (i+1))
```

Quando você faz isso estará somando duas sequências. Listas são sequências e strings são sequências. Como o retorno de `input` sempre é uma string, são exibidas as aspas no seu resultado:

```
Vetor Original ['1', '2', '3']
```

E se informar números com mais de um dígito, como string é uma sequência, ela será iterada e adicionando na sua lista um a um. Ao digitar `100` no `input`, aparecerá `['1', '0', '0']` no resultado. Isso porque somar sequências significa mesclá-las; uní-las na mesma sequência.

Como pretende trabalhar com inteiros, basta fazer:

```
lista = []

for i in range(n):
  lista.append( int(input("Informe o valor de x%d: " % (i+1)) )
```

Utilizando o `append` você está inserindo um valor por vez na lista, não mais mesclando como era originalmente.

Comment: ahhhh compreendi agora, obrigada

Comment: %d ? em 2021 ?  usa f-strings